# Reading from external HDD fails after writing to it

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure

I store all of my data on an external 5TB USB 3.0 HDD. I also have an external 3TB USB 3.0 HDD that I periodically backup my 5TB to (I only have about 2TB of data). The hard-drives used to be used by a Mac in the house, and so every file on the drives had a hidden .dstore file associated with them. When I moved to Windows, I formatted the 3TB drive as NTFS, copied the data over to it, then formatted the 5TB as NTFS and copied the data back over. That got rid of the Apple Partitions but I still had the .dstore files to deal with (in hindsight I could have fixed that while copying, instead of using the steps below. Live and learn)

To solve for that, I installed Beyond Compare and synchronized the 5TB over to the 3TB. I setup my filter so that the .dstore files were not included. That took a long time.  I went to bed and slept for 6 hours, got up and it was still copying. I left for work and it finished sometime during the day. When I got home, I then formatted the 5TB and had planned on just copying all of the data over to it like I did when I moved off the Apple Partition. This however is where my issues started.

It doesn't matter if I use Beyond Compare or Windows Explorer, copying my data from the 3TB over to the 5TB fails with error code `0x800701E3`. Both Windows and BC tell me it's a fatal hardware issue, but it doesn't tell me on which device. Initially, the copy starts and it tells me it'll be done in 1 hour and 15 minutes. Then it hits the same location on the disk every time and falls to an ETA of 27 days, then fails. At first glance I would assume the 3TB drive now hosting my data is failing, and not the 5TB. Since it happens at the same location (usually stops at the exact same file), I'm thinking the OS can't read data from the 3TB at that location. I've tried using different USB hubs, and I've tried it with different combinations of USB ports on my machine but it seems to not make a difference.

Unfortunately, this is now the only place I have all of this data (lesson learned, have more than 1 backup). Does this sound like hardware failure to you guys? If so what steps can I take to get that data off safely? I have the super important stuff, like all of my family photos and videos, on the drive synced to Google Drive. So worse case is I can download my 600gb Google Drive directory again. The other 1TB of data is my iTunes media and my Plex media. I can re-download the iTunes library and I still have all of the physical discs to re-create my Plex library. I just have a limit of 500GB of download per month at my ISP so getting that data back will take me a couple months of incremental downloads. The Plex library will take weeks to re-create (DVD/Blu-Rays take forever to convert!). I'm really hoping you guys can give me some guidance on tools or approach I can take to try and get the data off onto my 5TB drive safely.

Note: I typically keep a complete backup on BackBlaze, but when I moved the license to my Windows machine the backup was deleted from BackBlaze. BackBlaze needed 93 days to fully backup my data and this happened 3 days into that 93. Another lesson learned, don't touch your data until it's backed up off site.

**EDIT**

The Health tab in HD Tune showed the following messages:

```
HD Tune Pro: WD      My Book 1234 Health

ID                              Current  Worst    ThresholdData     Status   
(01) Raw Read Error Rate        200      200      51       20611    ok       
(03) Spin Up Time               184      177      21       5766     ok       
(04) Start/Stop Count           80       80       0        20139    ok       
(05) Reallocated Sector Count   200      200      140      0        ok       
(07) Seek Error Rate            100      253      0        0        ok       
(09) Power On Hours Count       92       92       0        6313     ok       
(0A) Spin Retry Count           100      100      0        0        ok       
(0B) Calibration Retry Count    100      100      0        0        ok       
(0C) Power Cycle Count          80       80       0        20119    ok       
(C0) Unsafe Shutdown Count      178      178      0        16819    ok       
(C1) Load Cycle Count           101      101      0        298796   ok       
(C2) Temperature                108      97       0        42       ok       
(C4) Reallocated Event Count    200      200      0        0        ok       
(C5) Current Pending Sector     200      200      0        15       warning  
(C6) Offline Uncorrectable      100      253      0        0        ok       
(C7) Interface CRC Error Count  200      200      0        0        ok       
(C8) Write Error Rate           100      253      0        0        ok       

Health Status         : warning
```

I ran an Error Scan as well and it showed 137 errors:

[image]

```
HD Tune Pro: WD      My Book 1234 Error Scan

Scanned data   : 2838 gB
Damaged Blocks : 5.5 %
Elapsed Time   : 10:23:45
1  Error at 12229 MB (LBA 25045050)
2  Error at 13253 MB (LBA 27143866)
3  Error at 13257 MB (LBA 27150650)
4  Error at 13258 MB (LBA 27154106)
5  Error at 13269 MB (LBA 27174970)
6  Error at 13324 MB (LBA 27288506)
7  Error at 13331 MB (LBA 27302202)
8  Error at 13332 MB (LBA 27305530)
9  Error at 13334 MB (LBA 27308986)
10  Error at 13336 MB (LBA 27312442)
11  Error at 13339 MB (LBA 27319610)
12  Error at 13341 MB (LBA 27323066)
13  Error at 13342 MB (LBA 27326394)
14  Error at 13344 MB (LBA 27329850)
15  Error at 13346 MB (LBA 27333178)
16  Error at 13346 MB (LBA 27333306)
17  Error at 13347 MB (LBA 27336634)
18  Error at 13349 MB (LBA 27340090)
19  Error at 13351 MB (LBA 27343418)
20  Error at 13352 MB (LBA 27346874)
21  Error at 13356 MB (LBA 27354042)
22  Error at 13358 MB (LBA 27357498)
23  Error at 13359 MB (LBA 27360954)
24  Error at 13361 MB (LBA 27364282)
25  Error at 13363 MB (LBA 27367738)
26  Error at 13364 MB (LBA 27371066)
27  Error at 13364 MB (LBA 27371194)
28  Error at 13366 MB (LBA 27374522)
29  Error at 13368 MB (LBA 27377978)
30  Error at 13369 MB (LBA 27381306)
31  Error at 13373 MB (LBA 27388474)
32  Error at 13373 MB (LBA 27388602)
33  Error at 13374 MB (LBA 27391930)
34  Error at 13376 MB (LBA 27395386)
35  Error at 13379 MB (LBA 27402170)
36  Error at 13381 MB (LBA 27405626)
37  Error at 13383 MB (LBA 27408954)
38  Error at 13383 MB (LBA 27409082)
39  Error at 13384 MB (LBA 27412410)
40  Error at 13386 MB (LBA 27415738)
41  Error at 13386 MB (LBA 27415866)
42  Error at 13388 MB (LBA 27419194)
43  Error at 13391 MB (LBA 27426490)
44  Error at 13393 MB (LBA 27429818)
45  Error at 13395 MB (LBA 27433274)
46  Error at 13396 MB (LBA 27436602)
47  Error at 13396 MB (LBA 27436730)
48  Error at 13398 MB (LBA 27440058)
49  Error at 13400 MB (LBA 27443514)
50  Error at 13401 MB (LBA 27446842)
51  Error at 13403 MB (LBA 27450298)
52  Error at 13405 MB (LBA 27453626)
53  Error at 13405 MB (LBA 27453754)
54  Error at 13408 MB (LBA 27460922)
55  Error at 13410 MB (LBA 27464250)
56  Error at 13410 MB (LBA 27464378)
57  Error at 13411 MB (LBA 27467706)
58  Error at 13413 MB (LBA 27471162)
59  Error at 13415 MB (LBA 27474490)
60  Error at 13415 MB (LBA 27474618)
61  Error at 13416 MB (LBA 27477946)
62  Error at 13418 MB (LBA 27481402)
63  Error at 13420 MB (LBA 27484730)
64  Error at 13421 MB (LBA 27488186)
65  Error at 13425 MB (LBA 27495354)
66  Error at 13427 MB (LBA 27498810)
67  Error at 13428 MB (LBA 27502138)
68  Error at 13428 MB (LBA 27502266)
69  Error at 13430 MB (LBA 27505594)
70  Error at 13432 MB (LBA 27509050)
71  Error at 13433 MB (LBA 27512378)
72  Error at 13435 MB (LBA 27515834)
73  Error at 13437 MB (LBA 27519290)
74  Error at 14517 MB (LBA 29732026)
75  Error at 14521 MB (LBA 29739322)
76  Error at 14522 MB (LBA 29742650)
77  Error at 14522 MB (LBA 29742778)
78  Error at 14524 MB (LBA 29746106)
79  Error at 14526 MB (LBA 29749562)
80  Error at 14527 MB (LBA 29752890)
81  Error at 14529 MB (LBA 29756346)
82  Error at 14531 MB (LBA 29759674)
83  Error at 14531 MB (LBA 29759802)
84  Error at 14532 MB (LBA 29763130)
85  Error at 14534 MB (LBA 29766586)
86  Error at 14536 MB (LBA 29769914)
87  Error at 14539 MB (LBA 29777210)
88  Error at 14541 MB (LBA 29780538)
89  Error at 14541 MB (LBA 29780666)
90  Error at 14542 MB (LBA 29783994)
91  Error at 14544 MB (LBA 29787450)
92  Error at 14546 MB (LBA 29790778)
93  Error at 14547 MB (LBA 29794234)
94  Error at 14549 MB (LBA 29797562)
95  Error at 14551 MB (LBA 29801018)
96  Error at 14552 MB (LBA 29804474)
97  Error at 14556 MB (LBA 29811642)
98  Error at 14558 MB (LBA 29815098)
99  Error at 14561 MB (LBA 29821882)
100  Error at 14563 MB (LBA 29825338)
101  Error at 14564 MB (LBA 29828666)
102  Error at 14566 MB (LBA 29832122)
103  Error at 14568 MB (LBA 29835450)
104  Error at 14569 MB (LBA 29838906)
105  Error at 14573 MB (LBA 29846074)
106  Error at 14574 MB (LBA 29849530)
107  Error at 14576 MB (LBA 29852986)
108  Error at 14578 MB (LBA 29856314)
109  Error at 14579 MB (LBA 29859770)
110  Error at 14581 MB (LBA 29863226)
111  Error at 14583 MB (LBA 29866554)
112  Error at 14584 MB (LBA 29870010)
113  Error at 14586 MB (LBA 29873338)
114  Error at 14588 MB (LBA 29876794)
115  Error at 14591 MB (LBA 29883962)
116  Error at 14591 MB (LBA 29884090)
117  Error at 14593 MB (LBA 29887418)
118  Error at 14595 MB (LBA 29890874)
119  Error at 14596 MB (LBA 29894202)
120  Error at 14598 MB (LBA 29897658)
121  Error at 14600 MB (LBA 29901114)
122  Error at 14601 MB (LBA 29904442)
123  Error at 14603 MB (LBA 29907898)
124  Error at 14608 MB (LBA 29918522)
125  Error at 14610 MB (LBA 29921850)
126  Error at 14611 MB (LBA 29925306)
127  Error at 14613 MB (LBA 29928634)
128  Error at 14613 MB (LBA 29928762)
129  Error at 14618 MB (LBA 29938874)
130  Error at 14620 MB (LBA 29942330)
131  Error at 14625 MB (LBA 29952954)
132  Error at 14628 MB (LBA 29959738)
133  Error at 14630 MB (LBA 29963194)
134  Error at 14633 MB (LBA 29969978)
135  Error at 14635 MB (LBA 29973434)
136  Error at 14638 MB (LBA 29980218)
137  Error at 14643 MB (LBA 29990842)
```

Comment: The way to tell for certain which drive is failing is to attempt the copy to/from each drive to a different drive than the other.

Comment: I re-plugged both drives into my machine and the 5TB doesn't show itself as being plugged in now. I also forgot until just now that while troubleshooting, I re-formatted the 5TB a second time. It took Windows 14 hours to format it. The 3TB I just did a quick format, so I don't have a way to compare times. The 3TB however just failed again, trying to copy data off of it onto my local SSD. Failed at the same location, trying to copy one of the two files it always fails on.

Comment: When the failure happens, I can't get the copy process to cancel without unplugging the drive. It will sit there for an hour trying to cancel and never cancel the operation once it fails.

Comment: So sector or just file issue on the 3TB. Likely total failure on the 5TB. BTW, I've used Crashplan for a few years and have been able to change computers without losing the backups. Perhaps something to look into.

Comment: Thanks, after unplugging the USB Hub, and replugging it back in, the 5TB came up immediately. It's possible the failure on the 3TB was causing some issues with I/O over the Hub. Any recommendations for getting data off the 3TB?

Comment: At the moment I'm ignoring the Google Drive folder (which is where the bad sector appears to be at) and copying over my iTunes and Plex directories (only remaining directories on the drive). Thus far, it's going without a hitch. If I can get everything but Google Drive off, then I can just re-download the GDrive data.

Comment: Run SMART tests on both drives. [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Updated my OP with the results, it doesn't look good. Is there a way to tell if it's hard or soft damage to the drive?